# Why is JavaScript prototype property undefined on new objects?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm fairly new to the concept of JavaScript's prototype concept.

Considering the following code :

```
var x = function func(){
}

x.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log("1");
}

var b = new x();
```

As I understand it, `b.log()` should return 1 since `x` is its prototype. But why is the property `b.prototype` undefined?

Isn't `b.prototype` supposed to return the reference to the `x` function?

Comment: No, `b.prototype` is _not_ supposed to be `x`. That's simply not how prototypes work in JavaScript. Are you thinking of the `__proto__` property? http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/139010

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Only constructor functions have prototypes. Since `x` is a constructor function, `x` has a prototype.

`b` is not a constructor function. Hence, it does not have a prototype.

If you want to get a reference to the function that constructed `b` (in this case, `x`), you can use

```
b.constructor
```

Comment: Peter, do you have a recommendation as to what book/online resource to read about all of the JS object model?

Comment: @VictorPiousbox The most precise and detailed source is the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/) but it might be hard to read if you're not used to reading that sort of thing. Beyond that, I would just search for information using a search engine.

Comment: After reading so many articles saying every object has prototype, I considered even objects created from function(using new) have one! But now I got it.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp says "Every JavaScript object has a prototype. The prototype is also an object." which contradiction of  your answer where you says Only constructor functions have prototypes

Answer (score 25):

The `.prototype` property of a function is just there to set up inheritance on the new object when the function is invoked as a constructor.

When the new object is created, it gets its internal *`[[Prototype]]`* property set to the object that the function's `.prototype` property points to.

The object itself doesn't get a `.prototype` property. Its relationship to the object is  completely internal.

That's why it works to do `b.log()`. When the JS engine sees that the `b` object itself has no `log` property, it tries to look it up on the objects internal *`[[Prototype]]`* object, where it successfully finds it.

To be clear, the *`[[Prototype]]`* property is not directly accessible. It's an internal property that is only indirectly mutable via other constructs provided by the JS engine.

Answer (score 16):

All ordinary objects in JavaScript have an internal prototype slot (note: the prototype here does not refer to the prototype property). The ECMAScript standard (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) specifies that this slot is referred to as [[Prototype]]. You could access this slot through the  __proto__ property.

__proto__ may not be reliably available across browsers. __proto__ becomes an official property in ECMAScript 6

The prototype property is, however, a property on a constructor function that sets what will become the __proto__ property on the constructed object.

You can access the prototype property of certain types, e.g., the core JavaScript types (Date, Array, and etc). Also a JavaScript function (, which can be regarded as a constructor) has a public prototype property. However, instances of a function do not have a prototype property.

In you case, `var b = new x();`, b is an instance of function x. Thus b.prototype is undefined. However, b does have an internal [[Prototype]] slot. If you output `b.__proto__` in Google Chrome e.g., version 63.0.3239.132, or Firefox such as version 43.0.4

```
console.log(b.__proto__);
```

You will see its [[Prototype]] slot as below:

```
{log: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
```

That's it.

---

And just for your reference, the whole code snippet is put as below:

```
var x = function() {
};
x.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log("1");
}

var b = new x();
b.log();  // 1

console.log(b.prototype); // undefined
console.log(b.__proto__); // {log: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
console.log(x.prototype); // {log: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
```

Comment: constructor is hidden property by default. am i right.

Comment: @Atul, not sure if you meant Object.prototype.constructor. The constructor property returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object. You can access it, e.g., `var c = new x.prototype.constructor();` or `var d = new b.__proto__.constructor();`

Answer (score 14):

Before going through your code I want to make sure some concept of prototype that are required to understand your code behavior.

1. `[[prototype]]` is a hidden property of a JavaScript object.This hidden property is nothing but a link to `Object.prototype`(If created by object literals).There is no standard way to access this `[[prototype]]` property.
2. Functions in JavaScript are objects so they also have `[[prototype]]` property.Here, In case of function this hidden property is a link to `Function.prototype`.There is also no standard way to access this `[[prototype]]` property.
3. Apart from this hidden link `[[prototype]]`, Whenever a function object is created,a `prototype` property is created within it, which is separate from hidden `[[prototype]]` property.

Now coming to your code :

> var x = function func(){}

When this line execute , a function object `x` is created with two links :

- Function.prototype (not accessible),
- x.prototype (accessible).

> x.prototype.log = function() {
>     console.log("1");
>   }

as we know now that `x` is a function object so `x.prototype` is accessible, so here you are able to include log method with it.

> var b = new x();

`b` is an object but not function object .It has that hidden link `[[prototype]]` but It is not accessible. so when you try to access like `b.prototype` it gives `undefined` as a result.If you want to check the prototype of `b` than you can see `(x.prototype).isPrototypeOf(b);` it will return `true`. so you can say that hidden link is referenced to `x.prototype`.

Here are some facts about prototype :

1. If object `O` is created with `O = new func(){}` then O[[prototype]] is `Function.prototype`.
2. If object `O` is created with `O = {}`then O[[prototype]] is `Object.prototype`.
3. If object `O` is created with `O = Object.create(obj)` then O[[prototype]] is `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `prototype` is a property of functions (actually, constructors), since it defines the properties/methods of objects of this class (those which were created from the constructor this prototype belongs). Take a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)