# Adding prototype to an object is giving error

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to add prototype to already created object Instance (Person1) in this example, but it is not getting successfully added, and thereby giving error. Can someone help me out?

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

var person = function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
this.printName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
}
}
person.prototype.printAge = function(){
alert(this.age);
}

var person1 = new person("Jack", 29); 
person1.prototype.printMessage = function(){
alert("Hello Friend"); 
}

var person2 = object.create(person1);
person2.printName();
person2.printAge();
person2.printMessage();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cause `object` is not `Object`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `person` is a function and `person1` is an object. Use `constructor.prototype` to solve the problem.

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

var person = function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
this.printName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
}
}
person.prototype.printAge = function(){
alert(this.age);
}

var person1 = new person("Jack", 29); 
person1.constructor.prototype.printMessage = function(){
alert("Hello Friend"); 
}

var person2 = Object.create(person1);
person2.printName();
person2.printAge();
person2.printMessage();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `__proto__` is not a feature.

Comment: @JonasW. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Only constructor functions have protoype property (functions which sets the property values via this.propertyName. Although you can use

```
__proto__
```

it is deemed inefficient.

Check this.

[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450731/why-is-javascript-prototype-property-undefined-on-new-objects)